# Templates in Ractive.js

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I am new to Ractive.js and just playing around with it. I am trying to build a simple app, but strangely, it's not working on my pc and I am getting an error in console "Could not find template element with id #template", where #template refers to the id assigned to script tag. Nothing gets rendered on my browser. However, the same code is running fine in JSFiddle. Can someone explain what is happening here?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dk49/2tstwLy2/1/) is the fiddle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Get Weather Details</title>
<meta name="description" content="Get weather for your city">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="weather.css">
<script src='https://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js'></script>
<script src="weather.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main" class="page-container">
    <script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
        <div class="weather-widget">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>City Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter City Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Recent Searches</label>
                <select>
                    <option>Select from recent searches</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="weather-details">
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Wind</th>
                            <td>{{country}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code in weather.js:

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
el: '#main',
template: '#template',
data: {
    country: 'London'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time weather.js executes, the element hasn't yet been created. You could either move the `<script src='weather.js'></script>` tag to the bottom of the page (inside `<body>`, after the topmost `<div>` containing the template element the script refers to), or add a `defer` attribute: `<script defer src='weather.js'></script>`.

Comment: No, it's not a utility library. There are already dozens of ways to solve the problem, including one-liners you can copy and paste from SO – no need to pollute things with yet another

Comment: in the above example, my observer is observing the city input element as well as select element. Whenever there is a change, it triggers an ajaz request. However, I am also updating the select element whenever a new city is entered, which is causes the ajax request to be fired again with same city as it detects a change in select element. Is there anyway to prevent this? I have updated the JSFiddle so you can see the code, but the ajax requests are failing because the api is providing data over http, while JSFiddle is loaded on https, so it is not allowing the calls.